# How to change the background-image in ace editor?

Tags: javascript, html, css, editor, ace-editor

I tried this in **CSS**, but it didn't work.I also tried a photo saved on
 my computer

```
.ace_identifier{
 background-image : url("https://www.google.com.eg/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwji1duTxbrTAhUEOBQKHamBCvQQjRwIBw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fox-fest.org%2F2017%2F02%2F06%2Fupcoming-workshop-coding-with-morgan-stanley%2F&psig=AFQjCNECub5OZqaxX9R684Gm4HLX-X7Zdw&ust=1493035590367032");
}
```

.ace_identifier{
 background-image : url("https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/1c/da/05/1cda057bcd14d46c68e3051dc26f6850.jpg");
}

EDIT:
I tried a working url.Same problem

Comment: your url is not working?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dalinhuang/c0wdg27h/

Comment: @DanielH i tried another one.

Comment: do you want to add background image to the whole editor or to specific word, should it be behind the gutter?

Answer (score 5):

css should work if you apply it to correct selector, and make sure there are no rules overriding it.

```html
<script src=http://ajaxorg.github.io/ace-builds/src-noconflict/ace.js></script>
<script>
var editor = ace.edit()
// set class to editor to use in css,
// could use .ace_editor too, but that
// would match all editors on the page
editor.container.classList.add("myEditor")
editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai")
editor.setValue("some text here", -1)
document.body.appendChild(editor.container)
</script>

<style>
.myEditor {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; top: 0;  
  background :  url(https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/1c/da/05/1cda057bcd14d46c68e3051dc26f6850.jpg);
}
}

</style>
```

Comment: You sir,are a genius ! Thank you sooo much !!! I never thought about the container method ! Thank you :)

Comment: Seems the class needs to be defined properly to take effect, e.g use tailwind class `bg-red-400`.